# Do I need a comma in this sentence before the word repeatedly?

Tags: commas

> "I could clearly see her trying to push it back to where it was supposed to be repeatedly and without success."

I'm thinking that this is OK, but it seems to be a long sentence, and I naturally pause after the word 'be' when speaking it outloud.
Maybe I need one AFTER repeatedly?

Comment: IMO, a comma would improve it, and a relocation of *repeatedly and without success* to right after "push it" would improve it even more.

Comment: @Tromano Agreed on both counts.  To be clear, you would need commas before and after the phrase to set it off from its surroundings.  "...to push it, repeatedly and without success, back to..."

Answer (score 2):

*"I could clearly see her trying to push it back to where it was supposed to be repeatedly and without success."*

1: That is a long and complicated sentence, and as an editor, I would probably suggest rephrasing it.

2: If you keep the sentence as-is in word-order, you *absolutely* need a comma after "to be," so that the eye does not try to parse "supposed to be repeatedly" as meaning "it was repeatedly supposed to be [somewhere]."

To expand on 2, it's not the point that "well, people wouldn't read it that way, because it doesn't make sense." Sometimes missing commas change meaning greatly, and sometimes you can puzzle out the intent *fairly* quickly. And sometimes the lack of commas turns a sentence into a hot mess and you throw it back at the author saying, "I do not know what the heck you are trying to say here, so fix it."

But in the middle ground there, where you can puzzle it out by figuring out which interpretation makes sense -- why a comma? Because the goal of writing is to communicate as smoothly as possible, and the more your reader is trying to puzzle stuff out, the less information they're going to retain, and the less happy they are going to be.

*Even if it is clear that there is only one logical meaning,* the reader is still using mental energy to weed out the illogical results, and you never want the reader using mental energy for anything but the essentials. This is especially true if you intend to write things and get paid, you never want the reader having to puzzle out what you meant, *ever*, because the reader will either stop reading it, or they will vow never to waste money on you again. And this is a *bad outcome* if you want to be paid for your writing.

Even if you're not getting paid, though, you still want to be clear in your writing; if people are spending mental energy weeding out the illogical meanings, they start forgetting other parts of the previously-read material, and/or they leave a little bit of their mind worrying at the confusing sentence... which means they don't grasp the *next* sentences as fully. This leads to confusion in the reader, and mistakes in the workplace.

Commas are vital.

Answer (score -2):

**Repeatedly and without success** is an adverbial phrase of manner, which should come before an adverb of place, **to (the place) where**. We don't usually put a comma when only two items are joined by the coordinating conjunction, **and**.

I suppose one can use a comma for the purpose of emphasis: **repeatedly, and without success**. The sentence, however, looks better without the comma.

> I could clearly see her trying to push it back repeatedly and without success to where it was supposed to be.

Comment: The poster isn't suggesting a comma there, but *in front of* "repeatedly" -- "back, repeatedly and without success." (Which is, indeed, the correct and *vital* place to put a comma in the sentence as it stands.)

Comment: @A.Beth To be fair, the original question does end with the comment, "Maybe I need one AFTER repeatedly?" While I agree that the comma should go before repeatedly, the poster actually did not only suggest, but directly state, that maybe a comma should go there. :)